# String Enum on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I've got an issue about inserting an enum into a `VARCHAR` field.
That's my enum:

```
public enum StatusPesquisaEnum {

    ATENDIDO("A"),
    ESPERA("E"),
    EMATENDIMENTO("EA"),
    NAOATENDIDO("NA");


    private StatusPesquisaEnum(String codigo){
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    private final String codigo;

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

}
```

I want to insert `A`, `E`, `EA` and `NA` into the database.
Furthermore I've tried a converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class StatusPesquisaEnumConverter 
        implements AttributeConverter<StatusPesquisaEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StatusPesquisaEnum status) {
        return status.getCodigo();
    }

    @Override
    public StatusPesquisaEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String codigoStatus) {
        return StatusPesquisaEnum.valueOf(codigoStatus);
    }
}
```

And it's mapped as:

```
@Column(name = "str_status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Convert(converter=StatusPesquisaEnumConverter.class)
private StatusPesquisaEnum statusPesquisa;
```

But it is inserting `ATENDIDO`, `ESPERA`, `EMATENDIMENTO` and `NAOATENDIDO` into the database.

Comment: Remove the `@Enumerated` as this conflicts with a custom converter.

Comment: Thank you, It partially worked! I've made some changes and I'll edit the post it! (y)

Comment: Please don't add the solution in the question. Either create a new answer or just leave my comment as answer...

Comment: This is not one of those forums you find on the net with the silly [SOLVED] text. Instead, if there's an answer that solves your problem, [mark is as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@Enumerated` as this conflicts with a custom converter:

```
@Column(name = "str_status")
@Convert(converter = StatusPesquisaEnumConverter.class)
private StatusPesquisaEnum statusPesquisa;
```